# ASP.NET Web Api fails on getJSON async

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET MVC with WEB API call, trying to understand why I get 'failed' when using async and 'success' when using sync ajax call

```
    <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-single" onclick="register(); ">Authenticate</button>
   </div>
```

//this method fails

```
function register() {
       var uri = '/api/RegisterAccount/GetSessionId';
            $.getJSON(uri)
                .done(function (data) {
                    alert('success');                    
                })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                alert('failed!!');
            });
        }
```

//this method success

```
function register() {
            var uri = '/api/RegisterAccount/GetSessionId';
            $.ajax({
                //type: "POST",
                url: uri,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {                
                    alert('failed!');
                }
            });
        }
```

//ASP.NET controller

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Security;
using CurrencyProtector.EbayProxy;
using CurrencyProtector.Models;

    namespace CurrencyProtector.Controllers
    {
        public class RegisterAccountController : ApiController
        {
            [Route("api/RegisterAccount/GetSessionId")]
            public string GetSessionId()
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                return "mysession";
            }
.
.
.
```

**EDIT** Just found out that it might be related to the Thread.Sleep on the controller

Comment: What is the actual error message you are recieving in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

When you use [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), it automatically calls [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) after getting the response. The data you've returned is just a string identifier and can not successfully be parsed as JSON. So, it it not your GET request that is failing, but actually the parsing of your data.

You get the same if you just try to parse the string you've provided:

```js
console.log($.parseJSON("mysession"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```